# Dormant users with filter days in prestashop 1.6

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to add  below query in $this_select with  left join but not working properly

Below is my working query which works fine :

```
  select      a.id_customer as id_customer,
        a.id_shop,
        a.email,
        a.lastname,
        a.firstname,
        max(c.date_add) as last_visit,
        IFNULL(max(b.date_add),'1001-01-01 00:00:00') as Last_order_date
 from        ps_customer a
 left join  ps_orders b
  on          a.id_customer = b.id_customer
 left join   ps_guest g 
 on          a.id_customer = g.id_customer
left join   ps_connections c
on          g.id_guest = c.id_guest
group by    a.id_customer
 having      to_days(Last_order_date) < to_days(now())- '30'
```

But my problem is that when I placed  below query code in my controller it is not taking the first and the second  left join:

```
    $this->_select='        
    a.id_shop,
    a.email,
    a.lastname,
    a.firstname,
    max(c.date_add) as last_visit,
    IFNULL(max(b.date_add),"'.$default_date.'") as Last_order_date
    ';

    $this->_join = '
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` b ON (a.`id_customer` =b.`id_customer`)';

    $this->_join ='left join   ps_guest g 
    on (a.id_customer = g.id_customer)';

    $this->_join ='left join   ps_connections c
    ON    (   g.id_guest = c.id_guest)      
    group by    a.id_customer
    having      to_days(Last_order_date) < to_days(now())- '.$dormant_filter_days.'';
```

Am I doing anything wrong in the  above $this_select or  $this_join  ??
Bleow is db exception which I get the problem is that I am not seeing my first two joins here ie it is not taking the first two joins

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry, did you try the below solution?

Comment: Yes but modified and  tried  without concatenating the joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding the `_join` value on each call to `$this->_join =`. You should use `$this->_join .=` for the second and last join.

```php
$this->_select = '          
    a.id_shop,
    a.email,
    a.lastname,
    a.firstname,
    MAX(c.date_add) AS last_visit,
    IFNULL(MAX(b.date_add), "' . $default_date . '") AS Last_order_date';

$this->_join = 'LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` b
    ON (a.`id_customer` = b.`id_customer`)';

$this->_join .= ' LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'guest` g 
    ON (a.id_customer = g.id_customer)';

$this->_join .= ' LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'connections` c
    ON (g.id_guest = c.id_guest)';

$this->_group = 'GROUP BY a.id_customer';

$this->_having = 'HAVING TO_DAYS(Last_order_date) < TO_DAYS(NOW()) - ' . $dormant_filter_days;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way which worked for me :

```
$this->_select='        
    a.id_shop,
    a.email,
    a.lastname,
    a.firstname,
    a.date_add  as registered_date,
    g.id_customer as guest_id,
    max(c.date_add) as last_visit,
    IFNULL(max(b.date_add),"'.$default_date.'") as Last_order_date
    ';
    $this->_join = '
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders` b ON (a.`id_customer`   =b.`id_customer`)     
    LEFT JOIN   ps_guest g      on (a.id_customer = g.id_customer)  
    LEFT JOIN   ps_connections c
    ON    (   g.id_guest = c.id_guest)      
    ';
    $this->_where = 'group by    a.id_customer having   to_days(Last_order_date) < to_days(now())- '.$dormant_filter_days.'  AND  to_days(a.date_add) < to_days(now())- '.$dormant_filter_days.' ';
    $this->_orderBy = 'id_customer';
    $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';
```